# loop to convert dataframe to np array chunk by chunk

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

is it possible to convert a dataframe to numpy array chunk by chunk with a loop. Something like this in pseudo code :

```
counter = 0
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    if (row['column']) == 1 :
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
 take the part of the dataframe where counter is <= 10 
 and convert it to numpy and restart the process at the next row
```

Comment: It is possible, but what is your goal?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could provide more detail to your goal...if you goal is to loop chunk by chunk over the df and convert into a single numpy array..what is the point? why not just use df.values? do you want to convert it by chunks and append the chunks to the same array? or different arrays for the chunks?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. Actually I am working with a very big dataset in a library called vaex, specifically designed for datasets too big for pandas to handle. When I try to convert it all to numpy, I have memory issues, as it has several hundred millions of rows. That's why I want to convert it bit by bit to a numpy array, and from those chunks, take only the values I want (say the first and the last of each column/chunk) to create a new array which will be much smaller (rough gess ~1 or 2 million rows)

Answer (score 1):

here's a couple approaches you could take that I started before your most recent comment..by the comment it seems that the first method might be useful for you if you adapt it a little

basically you can loop through the df in chunks and perform the operations you want on each chunk at a time instead of the entire df

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.rand(1000,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# LOOPING BY CHUNKS, STORING EACH CHUNK IN A NP ARRAY INSIDE A LIST
ix = 0
chunk = 10
arrays = []
for iy in range(chunk, len(df)+chunk, chunk):
    arrays.append(df.iloc[ix:iy].values)
    ix = iy

# ENTIRE DF TO NP ARRAY
array = df.values

# LOOPING BY CHUNKS, APPENDING EACH CHUNK TO A SINGLE NP ARRAY
ix = 0
chunk = 10
array = np.empty((0,3))
for iy in range(chunk, len(df)+chunk, chunk):
    array = np.concatenate((array, df.iloc[ix:iy].values))
    ix = iy
```

Comment: you could modify the first or last approach to create a list of np arrays with the parts of the chunk you want, or to make a new np array containing only the parts of the chunks you want

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this !

Comment: Just to clarify, what is ix = iy for please ?

Comment: each loop, the dataframe is cut using iloc from ix:iy indicies... iy is set by the loop and ix starts at 0..so the first loop is 0:10, then ix is set to iy so for the next loop its 10:20.. it's just to reset the beginning index of the next chunk to the end index of the current chunk

Comment: After tweaking the code for a while, I am getting closer to the result I need but I noticed that when I append a new array, it restarts with the first element every time, for example the first array is 10 elements long, the second one twenty(two 10 elements arrays) etc... how can I make it "forget" what was already put in the array, or drop from the memory what was already processed ?

Comment: get rid of the concatenation step

Comment: I am using the first solution with append sorry I didn't clarify. I tried to replace append with `arrays.insert(len(df), df[ix:iy])` but the problem persists.